# Link Node the Beginning of a Linked List

Tags: java, list, linked-list

I have two linked lists: killring and graveyard. When a node is "killed off" from killring, it is then added to the second linked list, graveyard. Everytime I add a new node to graveyard, I need to place this element to the beginning of this linkedlist. I'm not sure how to approach this. Conceptual or code response is much appreciated! Below is what I have so far:

```
public void kill(String name){
    AssassinNode victim = killring; 
    AssassinNode killer = killring; 
    if (gameOver() == true || killRingContains(name) == false) { // Check if game is over OR list contains name 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Game Over!"); 
    }
    while (killRingContains(name) == true) { // implements killRingContains to match targets
        killer = victim; // place the killer in the victim's place
        victim.next.player = name; // gets the victims name in list 
        graveyard = victim.next; // add the victim to the graveyard; 

        ..... // add victim to the beginning of graveyard   

    }
} // End of kill()
```

Comment: Why not just use LinkedList and call addFirst?

Comment: @Trey I'm assuming he's using his own version of a linked list and wants to know how to incorporate that method

Comment: The program is based on specs so I have: private AssassinNode killring; and private AssassinNode graveyard; - AssassinNode is a private static class.

Comment: @MitchWeaver then it's a duplicate of [Inserting Node at the beginning of a linked list](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36678677/476716)

Comment: I saw that program - it overcomplicates the solution that I need.

Comment: Did you not see the answer?

Comment: This would be so much easier if you just used `LinkedHashSet` or something instead. It's not even clear whether the victim is `victim` or `victim.next`.

Comment: @OrangeDog I just edit the question. I could use any of those suggestions, but that would not follow given specs for this program.

Comment: If [what I have already posted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36678747/476716) does not answer your question, then we have no idea what you're actually asking.

Comment: @Asteri, I don't understand what's going on in your loop at all. Can you please explain what you're trying to do there? You're looping but you're never iterating through the list, you're just doing the same thing to the "killring" node over and over again.

Comment: I solved the problem: victim.next = graveyard;

Answer (score 0):

```
victim.next = graveyard;
```

[new victim] --> [old victim] --> [older victim]